# Image zoom on hover with link

Tags: css, image, zooming

[I have this image zoom effect](http://jsfiddle.net/v8YLU/). How can I make `<a href="">Open image page</a>` link to appear on hover in the middle of the image?

Comment: Yes, if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v8YLU/3/)

You  have to just add `text-align:center` to the `<a>` tag of the `container_image` class

Also, made some style changes in the `<a>` tag like following:

```
.container_image a {
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s  ease-out; -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out; -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out; transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    text-align:center;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
}
.container_image:hover a {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, something like this but I've meant `<a href=..` to appear only on hover. I mean whole image will be link but in the middle of the image not under to have also `Open image page`.

Comment: @Goro Please check my updated fiddle in my answer again, Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's perfect. I will make some changes but is what I needed. Thank you!